# Not sure how to use function in pandas? Even if I pass the correct argument, got key error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby, pandas-datareader

```
     budget_(US_dollar)   revenue_(US_dollar)    profit   original_title

  0    150000000              1513528810      1363528810       Jurassic World
  1    150000000              378436354       228436354        Mad Max: Fury Road
  2    110000000              295238201       185238201        Insurgent
  3    190000000              1506249360      1316249360       Furious 7

def max_profit(column):
    df_max = df.iloc[df['column'].idxmax()]
    return df_max

max_profit('profit')

I got : KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\users\fubuki\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2645             try:
-> 2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2647             except KeyError:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'column'

After that I run **df_max** work correctly

budget_(US_dollar)                                              237000000
revenue_(US_dollar)                                            2781505847
profit                                                         2544505847
original_title                                                     Avatar


Note: above output is correct I could not able to provide all data because it's huge but analogy the same.
```

Why df_max print the correct output? even if above function is not working properly?
Why it is showing key error?

I am running the code in Jupyter Notebook.

Appreciate for your help and clearing the missing concept.

Comment: `df_max = df.iloc[df['column'].idxmax()]` remove the quotes in `'column'` so that the function actually uses the parameter. right now, it is looking for a column named `'column'` when you use that string.

Comment: `df['column']` uses the actual string `column`, not your parameter named `column`. Remove the quotes.

Comment: Oh..thank you very much silly mistake but I could not able figure out crap @ Phillyclause89. I am sorry to ask this kind question.

Comment: but tell me why df_max command was still working?